# Searching through contacts in android by name?

Tags: android, search, contacts

I want to implement dynamic search in android.
I want to find contacts starting by the alphabet entered by the user.
I am trying to implement it using SearchView.I have made a searchable activity and here is the code inside it

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
      Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
              new String[] {Data._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME},
              Data.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?" + " AND "
                      + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
              new String[] {query}, null);
      SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(null, 
              0, c, new String[] {Phone.DISPLAY_NAME}, null);
      setListAdapter(sca);
    }
```

I dont know where am I going wrong..I just dont get any results 
Any help would be appreciated!..Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

What value "query" variable contains? 
If it contains only the part of word, I think, you should use placeholder:

```
query = query + "%"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but I hope this help you or someone else who see this answer.
https://github.com/sachinmuralig/simple-multi-contact-picker